# Swift -Firebase get last childKey from a subset of snapshot.children

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

How can I get the last child key from a subset of child keys? For eg. in the loop I want to grab `Lqouwhrbcausobc8abc` and `Lkasjhvbafoshvb8xyz` in the `getLastChildKey()` function

db:

```
messageIds-userIds
    |
    @--currentUserId
           |
           @--XcAUw75y6vXBxCiNl3flrl9qcztob 
           |      |-Laouhfbobhvahsblask : 1
           |      |-Lwbiuwripibpiwbjvcp : 1
           |      |-Lqouwhrbcausobc8abc : 1  // I want to grab this messageId
           |
           @--ZBBglasjdbvj2X8zbMwasdbpBzOOp21w
                  |-Laofbhaphvbapsjvbpa : 1
                  |-Lljafhbvpojhfbvaljk : 1
                  |-Lkasjhvbafoshvb8xyz : 1  // I want to grab this messageId
```

code:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child(messageIds-userIds)

ref.child(currentUserId)
   .queryOrderedByKey()
   .queryLimited(toLast: 20)
   .observe( .value, with: { (snapshot) in

       for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {

           let userId = child.key

           self.getLastChildKey(from: userId, childSnapshot: child)
       }
})

func getLastChildKey(from userId: String, childSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {

    for child in childSnapshot.children {
            
        let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem when you run this code?

Comment: In the getLastChildKet function I get all the children from each individual user, I only need the last one from each user. Right now I’m get 6 results  (3 messageIds from both users) but I only want 2 results (the last messageId from each user)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to get just the last child node from each child node with a single read operation. While it is possible to get the last child node of a node, you will have to know the complete path of the parent node in that case.

This boils down to the fact that Firebase Realtime Database queries operate on a list of child nodes, and not on a tree.

- So you can request only the last (or first) child of `messageIds-userIds`, since you know the full path to that `messageIds-userIds` node.
- **If** you know the `currentUserId` then you can request the first/last child of that node too.
- And **if** you were to know both the `currentUserId` **and** `XcAUw75y6vXBxCiNl3flrl9qcztob`, then you could request the first/last child of that node too.

But if you only know the `messageIds-userIds` and want to get the last child of each of its `currentUserId/$XcAUw75y6vXBxCiNl3flrl9qcztob` child nodes, you will need to read the entire structure as you're doing now.

---

It often helps to model the data for the use-cases of your app. In this case, consider storing the last child node for each path in a single list.

```
lastChildNodes: {
    "currentUserId XcAUw75y6vXBxCiNl3flrl9qcztob": "-Lqouwhrbcausobc8abc"
    "currentUserId ZBBglasjdbvj2X8zbMwasdbpBzOOp21w": "-Lkasjhvbafoshvb8xyz"
}
```

---

Code sample:

```
func getLastChildKey(from userId: String, childSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
    DataSnapshot last = nil
    for child in childSnapshot.children {            
        snap = child as! DataSnapshot            
    }
    return snap
}
```

Comment: I didn’t think there was a way to do it. I honestly just did another read: **ref.child(currentUserId).child(userId).queryOrderedByKey().queryLimited(toLast: 1).observe( .childAdded...)** which works fine but seemed like an unnecessary read. Since there is no other way I’ll continue to use it because it works. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You don't need to perform another read. That's why I asked what wasn't working about the code you shared. Your `let snap = child as! DataSnapshot` will already have the last key after the loop is done, you just have to: 1) remote the `let` and make it a function-wide variable, 2) return the value at the end of the function. 3) check of the keys are sorted. If not, resort them (at which point you probably won't need the loop anymore).

Comment: You lost me. If I move the let outside of the loop (but still keep it within the function), how will that work? That went over my head. I just came up with this inside the same function, what do you think: **let maxCount = childSnapshot.childrenCount;  var count = 0; for child in childSnapshot.children { count += 1; if count == Int(maxCount) { ;let snap = child as! DataSnapshot; let messageId = snap.key }  }**

Comment: Declare the `snap` variable outside of the loop, and just have `snap = child as! DataSnapshot` inside the loop. Then `return snap` at the end, and you're good to go.

Comment: I’m still lost because of one thing, without **let maxCount = childSnapChildren.count**, **var count = 0**,  **count += 1**, and **if count == Int(maxCount) {}**, how will I know when the loop reaches the end? There doesn’t seem to be a **.last** property using a collection of Datasnapshots.